# Execute ssh script in webpage

Tags: php, bash, ssh

I have a shell script as below

```
#/bin/bash
SSHPASS='user'
SSHHOST='192.168.1.20'
SSHUSER='user'
ssh -t $SSHUSER@$SSHHOST << EOF
echo "Changing Directoy to Cloud"
cd /home/user/cloudit_2/it_cloud
git status
sleep 3
touch /tmp/abc.txt
ls -lah /tmp
rm -rf /tmp/abc.txt
sudo -S service ssh restart
$SSHPASS
EOF
```

This I wanted to run above script from Webpage, SO I have created I HTML File I below

```
<html>
<h1>Deploy</h1>
<form name="input" action="install.php">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</html>
```

install.php as below

```
<?php
 $output =  shell_exec("/bin/sh a.sh");
 echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

When I use php install.php it works fine. However when I tried to run it from webpage it didnt worked.

Comment: You should add **how** it isn't working

Comment: try using `exec` instead of `shell_exec`. This is highly dangerous though.

Comment: 1. Does php error_log contains anything relevant? 2. Why use form without GET or POST? Better make simple AJAX call...

Comment: `ALSO, note that shell_exec() does not grab STDERR, so use "2>&1" to redirect it to STDOUT and catch it.` http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Comment: Thanks, I have added "2>&1" and got below error    - : Could not create directory '/var/www/.ssh'.
Host key verification failed.

Comment: https://github.com/ericpaulbishop/redmine_git_hosting/issues/170

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Bozidar Sikanjic

I have followed below steps to nail down the issue

```
mkdir -p /var/www/.ssh
sudo -u www-data ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Copied id_rsa.pub to remote hosts (to which we are going to ssh in script) authorized _key file and this worked.

So it means apache user has right to login into remote host with ssh write.